# 2005 Honda Civic LX remote key will not lock doors while car in on, even when the remote is not inside car

Tags: honda, civic, locks

I bought a lock and unlock remote for my key chain from the dealership, as a delivery driver I'm often in and out of my car for mere seconds at a time, and quite often, so to lessen the blow to my car I leave the engine running unless I know I'm going to be more than a few seconds.

In some areas I would like to be able to lock my doors while I walk away from it even if its just for a second while it is running.

The dealership says nothing can be done. Is that really true though?

Answer (score 2):

You can obviously make any mods you like to a car, but they are not likely to be sanctioned by the dealership. Dealers will not want to sell this sort of thing for a couple of reasons:

- It will be a security risk
- It may invalidate your insurance
- It is likely to be a custom install

That said, technically it's an easy mod - you fit a locking system that is not slaved to the existing immobiliser/alarm system.